# anchor pseudo element text to be hidden

Tags: html, css

I need to make the **textsomething** text to set its font-size to 0 via css

I tried this

```css
.sample ul li a:before {
    font-size:0;
    }
```

```html
 <span class="">
    <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="#">
       ::before
     textsomething</a>
</li>
</ul>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do like following way. currently you are doing wrong way.

```css
.sample ul li a::before {
    content: "textsomthing";
    font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<span class="">
    <ul>
     <li>
       <a href="#">
      
     </a>
</li>
</ul>
</span>
```

Comment: hi ketan it is dynamically generated.I can't set content

Answer (score 1):

the way you adding text to pseudo class is not the correct way..this way you adding text to html element but in pseudo class you need to add text in css like this

```
.sample ul li a:before {
 content:"textsomething";
}
```

this will add text to pseudo class correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
.sample ul li a {
  font-size: 0;
}
```